Calculating Lyapunov exponent for 3D system
I am trying to calculate the Lyapunov spectrum of a Lorenz model,
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\frac{dx}{dt} =& \sigma(y - x), \\
\frac{dy}{dt} =& x(\rho - z) - y, \\
\frac{dz}{dt} =& xy - \beta z
\end{split}
\end{align}
using Wolf's algorithm and the following Fortran code given by Wolf himself. However, I am not getting the same answer as Determining Lyapunov exponents from time series. I think my error is due to the choice of nstep (total number of integration steps), irate (number of numerical integration time steps per re-orthonormalization), stpsze (integration step size), and io (the rate at which the output is generated). What should be the appropriate values of these terms?
program ode
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 3, nn = n * (n + 1), nn1 = nn + 1
    real(8) :: y(nn1), yprime(nn1), v(nn1), A(nn1), B(nn1), C(nn1), D(nn1)
    real(8) :: tme, t, stpsze
    integer :: nstep, io, m, i, j,k,irate
    real(8) :: ynorm(n), gsc(n), cum(n)

    ! Function prototype
    external :: fcn

    ! Input parameters
    write(*,*) 'Enter nstep, stpsze, irate, io :'
    read(*,*) nstep, stpsze, irate, io

    ! Initial conditions for nonlinear ODEs
    v = 1.0
    tme = 0.0

    ! Initial conditions for linearized ODEs
    v(n+1:nn) = 0.0
    do i = 1, n
        v((n+1)*i) = 1.0
    end do
    
    ! Time integration loop
    do m = 1, nstep
        do j = 1, irate
            ! Forward Euler integration steps
            y = v
            t = tme
            call fcn(t, y, yprime)
            A = yprime

            y = v + (stpsze * A) / 2.0
            t = tme + stpsze / 2.0
            call fcn(t, y, yprime)
            B = yprime

            y = v + (stpsze * B) / 2.0
            t = tme + stpsze / 2.0
            call fcn(t, y, yprime)
            C = yprime

            y = v + stpsze * C
            t = tme + stpsze
            call fcn(t, y, yprime)
            D = yprime

            ! Update using Runge-Kutta 4th order method
            v = v + stpsze * (A + D + 2.0 * (B + C)) / 6.0
            tme = tme + stpsze
        end do

        ! Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization
        ! Normalize the first vector
        ynorm(1) = sum(v(1:n)**2)
        v(1:n) = v(1:n) / sqrt(ynorm(1))

        ! Generate new orthogonal vectors
        do j = 2, n
            do i = 1, j - 1
                gsc(i) = dot_product(v(1:n), v(n+1:n*j))
                v(n+1:n*j) = v(n+1:n*j) - gsc(i) * v(n+1+(i-1)*n:n*i)
            end do

            ! Calculate the norm of the new vector
            ynorm(j) = sum(v(n+1+(j-1)*n:n*j)**2)
            v(n+1+(j-1)*n:n*j) = v(n+1+(j-1)*n:n*j) / sqrt(ynorm(j))

            ! Update running vector magnitudes
            cum(j) = cum(j) + log(ynorm(j)) / log(2.0)
        end do

        ! Output normalization exponent every io iterations
        if (mod(m, io) == 0) then
            do k = 1, n
                write(*, '(1x, F12.6)', advance='no') cum(k) / tme
            end do
            write(*, *)  ! newline
        end if
    end do

end program ode

subroutine fcn(t, y, yprime)
    implicit none
    real(8), intent(in) :: t, y(13)
    real(8), intent(out) :: yprime(13)
    integer :: i
    real(8) :: b, sg, r

    ! Parameters for Lorenz ODEs
    b = 4.0
    sg = 16.0
    r = 45.92

    ! Nonlinear Lorenz equations
    yprime(1) = sg * (y(2) - y(1))
    yprime(2) = -y(1) * y(3) + r * y(1) - y(2)
    yprime(3) = y(1) * y(2) - b * y(3)

    ! Linearized Lorenz equations
    do i = 1, 3
        yprime(3+i) = sg * (y(6+i) - y(3+i))
        yprime(6+i) = (r - y(3)) * y(3+i) - y(6+i) - y(1) * y(9+i)
        yprime(9+i) = y(2) * y(3+i) + y(1) * y(6+i) - b * y(9+i)
    end do

end subroutine fcn


What is it you get, what is it you expect, what is it you get from the other method, and what have you already done to figure out what the problem may be? All you're doing is show us a lengthy piece of code and say "it doesn't work, please debug it for me!"
